# How to check with which Heroku account I am currently logged in?

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

In the Heroku CLI (I am using WSL/Ubuntu), I would like to see with which Heroku account I am currently logged in.

The command `heroku login` starts a new login session but I want to know which account is currently active

I would expect (prefer) a list of accounts with which I have logged in, showing an asterisk (*) at the account I am logged in, OR, just a message "logged in as: account-email"

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-auth-whoami

Answer (score 21):

Display the current logged in user:

USAGE

```
$ heroku auth:whoami
```

ALIASES

```
$ heroku whoami
```

For more information: [Heroku CLI Commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-auth-whoami)